# JMeter doesnt stop its execution even after the scheduled duration

Tags: jmeter

Below is the details of my test plan.

> Number of Threads : 700
>   Loop Count : Forever   Scheduler
>   Configuration : Duration : 250 seconds

At 250th second, threads begin to stop as the scheduled duration is reached.
Even after 30 mins, the last 23 threads are not stopped and the test is not completed.

Tried to run the same test through non GUI mode as well. But the response is same.
Even after 30 mins, the test doesn't stop its execution.

Can you please help if i have missed any configuration..

Comment: can you please share the thread group configuration screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you are suffering from insufficient [Java Heap Space](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html#wp1085825) allocation. By default JMeter is started with 512 Mb heap only which is fine for tests development and debugging but will be not enough when it comes to real load test (like in your scenario with 700 users).

To overcome this:

1. Open JMeter startup script (`jmeter.bat` for Windows OS family, `jmeter` for other operating systems)
2. Locate line like `HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"`
3. Change both values to be something like 80% of your total available physical RAM
4. Restart JMeter to pick the changes up
5. And yes, never run load tests in GUI mode

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for more recommendations on JMeter tuning and tweaking in order to get the maximum throughput from the single instance